# How to get current location using Google App or GPS?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)

Hello I am new in Android development. i am working on android application . i want to know that how can i get current location address using Google map or GPS.

Comment: Try to do some google search
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/index.html

Comment: using Google maps or GPS????? whats this?

Comment: Actully I am working on an Android Application.In That i need that when i capture an image it should show location of image captured .i don't exactly what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below link :

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Its work for me .